# min-height or sticky footer which is preferred idea?

Tags: css, xhtml

If in content is too small in pages then it look odd . to show some space to make looks good which method would be better.

min-height to `#main-content` or sticky footer, which is preferred idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your audience and content. min-height isn't fully supported by all browsers, but there are ways around that.

The bottom line is that you need to make your website work for your content, not the other way around. If certain pages don't have very much content, you should consider consolidating pages  or coming up with more creative ways to display the content.

To bluntly answer your question, a sticky footer unnecessarily takes up valuable screen real estate. Unless there is important content in your footer, I would apply a min-height your #main-content.